# Generate style from xml in intellij (/android studio)

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, intellij-idea

Is there a way how to **generate style from XML attributes** so I don't have to manually copy paste 1 by 1? When I prototype, I use the "inline" styles then I want to export styles into styles.xml but manually it is time consuming task. It is just different format, should be easy to automate.

```
<ImageView
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="47dp"/>
```

**into**

```
<ImageView
        style="@style/h2_image"/>

<style name="h2_image">
    <item name="android:layout_width">80dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">47dp</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Very Simple.!

Just keep the cursor in the file from where you want to extract the style resource. Just a right click then click on refactor.

**Refactor -> Extract -> style/layout**.

[image: This bow will apear]

Then give style a name and there you go..!
For more you can refer the [documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2017.1/refactoring-android-xml-layout-files.html).

Comment: oh, cool, I thought there must be some simple way how to do this

Comment: Thank yu, this just made my life 1000% better.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like that:

```
<resources>
    <style name="CustomImgView">
        <item name="android:layout_width">80dp</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">47dp</item>
    </style>
</resources>

<ImageView style="@style/CustomImgView" />
```

more information: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/style-resource.html

Comment: oh - I was not clear enough - see updated answer please (I know how to use styles)

Answer (score 0):

Try to Declare your Style like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
      <resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <style name="YourCustomStyle">
            <item name="android:layout_width">"80dp"</item>
            <item name="android:layout_height">"47dp"</item>
             <!-- another attributes -->
            <item name="customAttr">value</item> 
        </style>
      </resources>
```

And in your `xml` add this `android:theme="@style/YourCustomStyle"`

Comment: oh - I was not clear enough - see updated answer please (I know how to use styles)